# Angular ngRepeat error '_item_' in '_item_ in _collection_' should be an identifier '(_key_, _value_)' expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I am trying below code

```
element.append('<label value="{{feat.Name}}">{{feat.Name}}</label><md-select ng-model="feat.Value"> <md-option><em>None</em></md-option> <md-option ng-repeat="x for x in feat.AllowedValues.split(\',\')"  ng-value="x.value" ng-disabled="$index === 1"/>{{x.value}}</md-option></md-select>');
```

and getting below error

> Error: [ngRepeat:iidexp] '*item*' in '*item* in *collection*' should
>   be an identifier or '(*key*, *value*)' expression, but got 'x for x'.

While when i tried with

```
element.append('<label value="{{feat.Name}}">{{feat.Name}}</label><select ng-model="feat.Value" ng-options="x for x in feat.AllowedValues.split(\',\')"></select>');
```

It worked can you tell me what is the issue with the first code?

Comment: are you using `Angular Material`?

Comment: Yes Angular material used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you did a little mistake `element.append('<label value="{{feat.Name}}">{{feat.Name}}</label><md-select ng-model="feat.Value"> <md-option><em>None</em></md-option> <md-option ng-repeat="x for x in feat.AllowedValues.split(\',\')"  ng-value="x.value" ng-disabled="$index === 1"` **/>** **(closed here)** `{{x.value}}</md-option></md-select>');`

we can close any element like

```
<element />
```

or

```
<element></element >
```

**Update**

Remove `x for` from `ng-repeat="x for x in feat.AllowedValues.split(\',\')"`. I don't know but it's not working with `<md-option>`

```
element.append('<label value="{{feat.Name}}">{{feat.Name}}</label><md-select ng-model="feat.Value"> <md-option><em>None</em></md-option> <md-option ng-repeat="allowedValue in feat.AllowedValues.split(\',\')"  ng-value="allowedValue" ng-disabled="$index === -1">{{allowedValue}}</md-option></md-select>');
```

Comment: Thanks i made typo changes and still i am getting same issue.

Comment: why did you add backslash into `feat.AllowedValues.split(\',\')"`?

Comment: To get the data as data look like Comma separated Strings

Comment: oh yes you are using in JS, I tried your HTML only :)